# Does $\lim_←$ and composite of field commutes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, limits-colimits

Does inverse limit and composite of field commutes?

For example, let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be fields.
We take $\lim$ with respect to $p$-th Frobenius (not surjective),
then,
$\lim K_1K_2＝(\lim K_1)(\lim K_2)$ ?

I guess this is true, but I couldn't find any reference for this. Reference (book, pdf, etc..) is also appreciated.

Comment: What is $K_1K_2$? Did you mean $\lim K_j = \bigcap_{n\ge 1} K_j^{p^n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very ambiguous.

Notations, assuming characteristic $p$:

- $K^{p^\infty}= \bigcap_{n\ge 1} K^{p^n}$
- $K^{1/p^\infty}= \{ a\in \overline{K}, \exists n, a^{p^n}\in K\}$.
- Let $\varprojlim K^{p^n} $ be the set/ring/field of sequences $(a_n)$ with $a_n\in K, a_n=a_{n+1}^p$. The map $(a_n)\to a_1$ is an isomorphism $\varprojlim_{n\ge 1}K^{p^n} \to K^{p^\infty}$.

Then look at $$K_1 = \Bbb{F}_p((x_0/x_1)^{1/p},(x_0/x_2)^{1/p^2},(x_0/x_3)^{1/p^3},\ldots )$$
$$K_2 = \Bbb{F}_p(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)^{1/p^\infty}$$
we get that $$
x_0\in (K_1K_2)^{p^\infty}, \qquad K_1^{p^\infty}=\Bbb{F}_p \implies x_0\not \in  
K_1^{p^\infty}K_2^{p^\infty}$$

Comment: Sorry for delayed replay, and thank you for your counter example, but I assume $K_i$ to be perfected.

Comment: It seems you don't understand the meaning of perfect

Comment: Sorry typos, perfectoid, not perfect.

Comment: Does the statement still has counter examples if we replace $K_1$ and $K_2$ to perfected field ?

Comment: What is a perfected field

Comment: sorry, perfectoid,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectoid_space. My PC exchange perfectoid  to perfected I don't know the reason why.

Comment: The Frobenius is in characteristic $p$, not on a $p$-adic space

Comment: Then, the name was not appropriate, Your example is very helpful, but my curiosity is in character 0 case. The name is not Frobenius, but x→x^p and inver limit as it's inverse system is in my thought.

Comment: I don't know what is $K^\flat$ for a $p$-adic field $K$

Comment: Sorry to bother, I try again. Thank you for your nice example.